# Will multiple Hearts of Fenrir trigger at the same time, or sequentially?

Tags: werewolv.es

What happens if all of wolfpack is dead and multiple people have a Heart of Fenrir? Do all holders become an Omegawolf, or does only one holder become an Omegawolf? (and are all or only one HoF consumed?)

Are all HoFs consumed when one person has multiple at the moment it triggers?

What happens if one person has multiple HoFs when wolfpack has died? Do they lose one or all HoFs upon becoming OW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Hearts would trigger at the same time, making multiple [Omegawolves](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/Omegawolf) a possibility.